# Physical router/modem security

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, modem

Concerns about customer data.  I own a small business within a 4 business building.  I recently had Comcast install my internet/network/voice with one of their modem/router combos.  They did the backroom work and left the modem/router for me to install in my space--but, my contractor had someone stick it in a phone/equipment room.  There are multiple keys with other tenants to this equipment room.  Comcast recommended for me to move it.

Q: 1.  If someone wanted to..can they plug in a network cable, to an available port, and gain access to my network without passwords?
Q: 2.  If someone pushed the wireless connectivity button (which gives access to whomever is trying to connect) they could also get access right?

Comment: For Q1 - Yes they will be in your network. They may not have access to your PCs, but they are in the same network and if they want, they can try to break into your system. Q2 - Yes, but usually the WPS feature can be disabled - and it is recommended for it to be disabled.

Comment: The most important thing for network security is the physical security - That means placing things like routers, modems and servers behind locked doors. As soon as the physical security is compromised, your whole network is compromised. In your case, I would move that modem ASAP!

Answer (score 2):

> Q: 1. If someone wanted to..can they plug in a network cable, to an available port, and gain access to my network without passwords?

Yes, they would be able to access the network. They don't necessarily get access to any services on that network (depending on how secure your system administrator set up services). They would be able to access the internet over your connection, which might be a security risk in itself.

> Q: 2. If someone pushed the wireless connectivity button (which gives access to whomever is trying to connect) they could also get access right?

Yes, and then the same concerns apply as above, with the exception that it is much harder to monitor (you can't look at the number of cables going to your router).

Answer (score -1):

In the settings of the router you should be able to turn off WPS which is the "connect" button in the router. Otherwise yes they can connect via that with no passwords.

And as the other member said, they will get in your network if they plug in

Comment: Once again, if you feel the need to downvote, ALWAYS write why...